# Plane cubic with two distinct singularities is reducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k=\overline{k}$ be a field and $C=V(f)\subset \mathbb{P}^2$, where $f\in k[x,y,z]$ is homogeneous of degree 3. I would like to show that if $f$ has two distinct singular points, then $C$ is reducible.

My idea: we can write $f$ as $$f(x,y,z)=a_1x^3+a_2x^2y+a_3x^2z+a_4xyz+a_5y^3+a_6xy^2+a_7y^2z+a_8yz^2+a_9xz^2+a_{10}z^3$$ where $a_i\in k$. Can we assume that the two singular points are $[0,0,1]$ and $[0,1,0]$? If so, this would imply that $a_5=\dots=a_{10}=0$. Then $$f(x,y)=a_1x^3+a_2x^2y+a_3x^2z+a_4xyz=x(a_1x^2+a_2xy+a_3xz+a_4yz),$$ so $C$ is reducible since $f$ factors.

Can I assume the singular points are $[0,0,1]$ and $[0,1,0]$? Does the fact that $f$ factors imply $C$ is reducible? If so, why? Is there a different way to solve this problem, perhaps using tangent spaces?

Comment: The easiest path is to use Bezout. Take the line joining the two points. If it is not a component, it can meet the cubic only 3 times, but at both the points the intersection multiplicity is at least 2, so the line meets the cubic at least four times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the singularities wherever you like. Putting them there
gives a factor of $x$. But just consider the line joining
the two singular points. Its intersection multiplicity with the cubic
at each singularity is at least two, and so its overall intersection
multiplicity with the cubic is at least four. This is too many, unless
the line is a component of the cubic.